# Store a second-line output in a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am making a little script to get users public/external IP address to cmd!
So it goes:

```
C:\...>nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | find /I "Address" > %temp%\_W___1.log

C:\...>set /p GPIPLOG=<%temp%\_W___1.log

C:\...>echo %gpiplog%
Address:  208.67.222.222

C:\...>type %temp%\_W___1.log
Address:  208.67.222.222
Address:  X.X.X.X

C:\...>echo %gpiplog:~2,50%
dress:  208.67.222.222
```

I'm thinking that `echo %gpiplog:~2,50%` will jump to second line and show everything until it reaches 50 characters, but I'm wrong!
What I want:

```
C:\...>echo %gpiplog:~2,10,50%
X.X.X.X
```

Comment: Shouldn't your find be using `internet address` for the search string.

Comment: Yeah but this can be used instead!

Comment: My suggestion is that you tell us what output you want returning from the initial command instead of what you think your commands may mean! In doing that, use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47537987/edit) and also include with it the output which is returned from the bare command, `nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com`.

Comment: You should be getting 3 lines of output with your code.  The first one being the ip address of the dns server. The second is the internet address and the 3rd is also the internet address.  Why do you want to make it harder on yourself.  If you want the internet address just use that in your find search string.

Comment: @Squashman, running that command on my PC outputs five parseable lines, two of which begin with `Address:  `

Comment: @Compo, so you get three lines with Internet Address?

Comment: @Squashman, no, just two containing an IP Address: Using the command, `C:\Users\Compo>nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com` 
_[1]_ `Server:  resolver1.opendns.com` 
_[2]_ `Address:  208.67.222.222` 
_[3]_ `Non-authoritative answer:` 
_[4]_ `Name:    myip.opendns.com` 
_[5]_ `Address:  2.98.166.15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@echo off
    cd %~dp0

```
if "%~1"=="-h" goto :help
if "%~1"=="-help" goto :help
if "%~1"=="/?" goto :help

type nul > %temp%\_W___getpipData.log
type nul > %temp%\_W___getpipDataL.log
type nul > %temp%\_W___getpipDataN.log

.\nslookup.emod myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | find /I "Address" > "%temp%\_W___getpipDataN.log"
more +01 "%temp%\_W___getpipDataN.log" > "%temp%\_W___getpipDataL.log"
del /F /Q "%temp%\_W___getpipDataN.log"
type "%temp%\_W___getpipDataL.log" | find /I "Address" > "%temp%\_W___getpipData.log"
del /F /Q "%temp%\_W___getpipDataL.log"
set /p GPIPLOG=<"%temp%\_W___getpipData.log"
echo %GPIPLOG:~10,50%
set /p GPIPLOG=
del /F /Q "%temp%\_W___getpipData.log"
exit /B

:help
echo.getpip - Get Public IP
echo.
echo.Usage: getpip
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

With a batch file with a loop forindo you can get what you want :

```bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in (
  'nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|find "Address:"'
) Do set "ExtIP=%%A"

Echo %ExtIP% & pause
```

Here is another batch script to get :

1. Private LAN IP (ipv4)
2. External Public IP
3. MAC Address

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Get (LAN ,Public) (IP) and MAC Addresses by Hackoo 2017
mode con cols=80 lines=5 & Color 9E
echo( & echo(
echo   Please Wait a While ... Searching for (LAN ,Public)(IP) and MAC addresses ...
Set "LogFile=%~dpn0.txt"
@for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 %ComputerName% ^| findstr [') do (
    set "LAN_IP=%%a"
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in (
  'nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>NUL^|find "Address:"'
) Do set ExtIP=%%A


@For /f %%a in ('getmac /NH /FO Table') do  (
    @For /f %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
        If /I NOT "%%b"=="N/A" (
            Set "MY_MAC=%%b"
        )
    )
)
    Cls 
    echo(
    echo                My Private LAN IP       : %LAN_IP%
    echo                My External Public IP   : %ExtIP%
    echo                MAC Addres              : %MY_MAC%

(
    echo My Private LAN IP      : %LAN_IP%
    echo My External Public IP  : %ExtIP%
    echo MAC Address            : %MY_MAC%

)>"%LogFile%"
Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak>nul
Start "" "%LogFile%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without see the full output of your code, you should consider just using **internet address** for your search string.  You can then capture the ip address by using a FOR command.

This can be run from the command line.  If you need it in a batch file, double the percent symbols per the FOR command help file.

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims== " %G IN ('nslookup -debug myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com 2^>nul^| find /I "internet address"') do echo %G
```